# Get only the specified styles of an element :)

Tags: javascript, styles

I can get a style of an element just doing this:

```
alert (document.defaultView.getComputedStyle (document.getElementById ("element"), null).getPropertyValue ("background-color"));
```

I can get all styles of an element just doing this:

```
var styles = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle (document.getElementById ("element"), null);
var string = ""

for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i ++) {
  string = string + styles[i] + ": " + styles.getPropertyValue (styles[i]) + "\n";
}

alert (string);
```

But, how can I get only the specified styles of an element?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'specified styles'? Do you mean:

```
var el = document.getElementById("element");
alert(el.style.display);
alert(el.style.background);
...etc...
```

or do you mean something like this:

```
function in_array (needle, haystack, argStrict) {
    var key = '', strict = !!argStrict;
    if (strict) {
        for (key in haystack) {
            if (haystack[key] === needle) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (key in haystack) {
            if (haystack[key] == needle) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var styles = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle (document.getElementById ("element"), null);
var string = "";
var whichStyles = ['display','background-color'];

for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i ++) {
    if(in_array(styles[i], whichStyles) {
        string = string + styles[i] + ": " + styles.getPropertyValue (styles[i]) + "\n";
    }
}
alert (string);
```